# Is it possible now to add inline VF page in Standard New/Edit page layout .

Tags: apex, activities

Is it possible now to add inline VF page in Standard New/Edit page layout . 
I need to add a VF page in standard New/Edit page of Task and Event.Can anyone please help me here.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inline VF pages appears only in detail page and cannot be added to New/Edit page layout. To add an inline VF page in detail page of Task see the below screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I never  asked about inline vf page for  detail page .

Comment: I said that it's not possible to add inline VF page to New/Edit page and provided steps to do it for detail page.